# Copy a value from one cell and paste it to another - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script:

```
function myFunction()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eric");
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("D50");
}
```

I want to copy the value (but not the formula) of cell `AG1` to cell `D50`.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I want to make it so that ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("D50"); the ("D50") part get data from cell "AG1" and Navigate to the data in the box, only taking the numbers that it displays and not the formula text in it.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: umm... me is want to get data from cell AG1 so me is able to use  in javascript with script ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("D50");

Comment: Is this Better?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. When you want to retrieve the value of cell "AG1", I thought that `sheet.getRange("AG1").getValue()` is used. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `me is want to get data from cell AG1 so me is able to use in javascript with script ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("D50");`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:**

As far as I understand, your goal is to get the value of cell `AG1` and set it to cell `D50`.

- You don't need to set active ranges.
- You just need to apply
  [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) to the `AG1` range to get the value and
  [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) to `D50` to set the value.

**Solution:**

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eric");
var AG1val = sheet.getRange('AG1').getValue(); // get the value of AG1
sheet.getRange("D50").setValue(AG1val); // set the value of AG1 to D50  
}
```